# Why am I getting errors in my code when using event listener?

Tags: events, listener

I have getting errors using event listener. Console keeps telling me to put a bracket in my `index.js` file, however when I put it there, it then says the bracket should not be there.

This is my HTML markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Drum Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <h1 id="title">Drum  Kit</h1>
  <div class="set">
    <button class="w drum">w</button>
    <button class="a drum">a</button>
    <button class="s drum">s</button>
    <button class="d drum">d</button>
    <button class="j drum">j</button>
    <button class="k drum">k</button>
    <button class="l drum">l</button>
  </div>
  <script src = "index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <footer>
    Made with ❤️ in London.
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #283149;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: #DBEDF3;
  font-family: "Arvo", cursive;
  text-shadow: 3px 0 #DA0463;

}

footer {
  color: #DBEDF3;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.w {

}

.a {

}

.s {

}

.d {

}

.j {

}

.k {

}

.l {

}

.set {
  margin: 10% auto;
}

.game-over {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.pressed {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 4px 0 #DBEDF3;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}

.drum {
  outline: none;
  border: 10px solid #404B69;
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-family: 'Arvo', cursive;
  line-height: 2;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #DA0463;
  text-shadow: 3px 0 #DBEDF3;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

And this is my index Java file:

```
var numberOfDrumButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length;

for (var i = 0; i<numberOfDrumButtons; i++); {
    document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click",function () {
        alert("I got clicked!");
    )};
}
```

I keep getting errors in the console saying that the ) bracket is missing in the 7th line when I put in the ) and when I don't, it says expected ) on line 7

Comment: you shouldn't have a semicolon here `i++); {`, that needs to just be `i++) {`. Overall this code is unnecessary anyway though, you can accomplish this by just looping through the result of querySelectorAll - `document.querySelectorAll(".drum").forEach(function(drum){
    drum.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        alert('I got clicked')
    })
})`